# Javascript for each textbox depend on drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I make input form using static row in 7 rows. How can I get selected value in each textbox when drop down list selected? I tried to use jQuery to do it, but my code is getting error (all textbox changed). So, below is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="nm_pot_part_shortage[]"]').on('change', function() {
      $('[name="nm_maker[]"]').val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Image of my form:

[image: each textbox depend on drop down list]

Comment: do you have a jfiddle of this?

Answer (score 1):

You must escape bracket notation by using double slashes for selector having name like `$('[name="nm_pot_part_shortage\\[\\]"]')`, otherwise you will get an error, see following code :

```
$( '[name=nm_pot_part_shortage\\[\\]]' ).on( 'change', function () {
   // get current value
   var selectVal = $( this ).val();
   // find the input by traversing up the parent first using .closest()
   // and use .find() to find particular input exist on the same rows with
   // select element, so this never go down to match another input exist on 
   // another rows
   $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).find( '[name=nm_maker\\[\\]]' ).val( selectVal );
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/sm4ut786/)*(example given were using table)*

Better case is just give all the select and input with the same class name for each element. As example give class name `myselect` to select element and `myInput` for input element, at the end JS code would be :

```
$('.mySelect').on('change', function () {
  var selectVal = $( this ).val();
  $( this ).closest( 'tr' ).find( '.myInput').val(selectVal);
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code, voilaaa it's work. Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: No worries, glad to hear that and you're welcome mate

Comment: But, i can't get value of nm_maker in database, here's my ddl code: <select name="nm_pot_part_shortage[]"  style="width:100px;" onChange="return data(this.value)">
    <option value="0">--PILIH--
      <?php
       $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mst_pot_part_shortage");
       while ($nm_pot_part_shortage=mysql_fetch_array($query))
       {
      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $nm_pot_part_shortage['nm_maker']?>"><?php echo $nm_pot_part_shortage['nm_pot_part_shortage']?>
      <?php
       }
      ?>
      
    </select>

Comment: **1)** So, all the values listed already on select element ? **2)** Is it all the rows dynamically created? **3)** If you used above JS code no need for `onChange="return data(this.value)"` this code

Comment: 1) yes, all values listed in select statement 2) rows static, limit to 7 rows only

Comment: Can you post `HTML` snippet for that rows along with JS

Comment: i created master part in table named mst_pot_part_shortage, consist of id, nm_pot_part_shortage, nm_maker

Comment: I meant `the code` snippet, not the elaboration cause i can't see how you implemented it. Anyway, ever try to give an alert `alert($(this).val())` inside change listener,and see the alert pop out or not, if yes, displaying value or not.

Comment: I've tried your js using alert and it display the value..in textbox nm_ maker i write <input name="nm_maker[]" id="nm_maker_1" value="" style="width:150px;" disabled> did you see the error, Sir?

Comment: Did't see the error. Are you using table for the rows? If not, `$( this ).closest( 'tr' )` might be failing you as well.  jQuery depend on HTML structure to find DOM element on page

Comment: yes, i using table for creating rows. All 7 rows in 1 table.

Comment: Weird, it should work. Once again, can you reproduce the code inside https://jsfiddle.net. Wanna see the WHOLE code instead of part of. Put only table part and js inside respective placeholder provided by fiddle

Comment: here's my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dee10/fmjjLz05/2/ not include my php code. i'm still stuck on it

Comment: Your select element is wrong, fix some : https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/99fcpxpd/ .Other than that everything is fine

Comment: still not working, Sir. I really confused face this code.

Comment: lol. Something wrong with the code. All the example are working. If you dont mind, can i remote you desktop to fix this using `teamviewer`. Cant stand with the code who did't run/execute.

Comment: Sorry, my company didn't allow others to remote. Can i send my sample code to your email, Sir?

Comment: I have been sent email. Please check, Sir.

Comment: i have read your code. Wanna ask something. Did the value selected from `select` element already show in respective `input`(not save in db yet)?

Comment: Yap, Sir... value selected from select element already show in respective input (still not save in db yet)

Comment: How come, i thought the value did't displayed inside that input. Misleading understanding. Anyway, remove `disabled` attribute inside all input to be like this : `<input name="nm_maker[]" id="nm_maker_15" value="" style="width:150px;">`, and try submit

Comment: i've removed "disabled". And it's working now (can save to db). But, the mistake is when "nm_pot_part_shortage" in db get a same value as "nm_maker". It seems wrong in my drop down list query.

Comment: Of course it is same because on `select` element's option the attr value use is `<?php echo $nm_pot_part_shortage['nm_maker']?>` , which is same with value you put inside `name="nm_maker[]"`, as a result, you saved into db with the same value

Comment: Can't remove one of them. Any idea how it come?

Comment: Provide each of them with different values

Comment: I've tried change both of them in different values but still not working.

Comment: Done! Solved. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

**Native Javascript:**

1) Give each dropdown an ID. This can be done in the HTML or dynamically in javascript.

2) Assign a function to each dropdown for an `onclick` event.

3) Retrieve the value as such:

```
function dropdownClicked(){
  var ID = this.id;
  var element = document.getElementById(ID);
  var value = element.value;
}
```